# What is the difference between “swirl” , “rotation , "spin" and " turn"”?

Tags: vocabulary, synonyms

While i was reading some article from The Times about John Surman's new album, i've seen the "Swirl" world and translate it. i was found the synonims. but i don't know where we should use w

Comment: Please start with a dictionary to look up these words. Also proofread and correct the English in the question, fix the spelling of "I" and "synonyms" and finish the last word starting "w".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swirl usually applies to fluids, often in a chaotic or unpredictable way. "swirling winds", for instance.
Rotation is describing the circular motion of an object, such as the Earth or a baseball. Spin could be used more or less interchangeably in this context. "Clockwise rotation" and "clockwise spin" mean the same thing.
Turn is the action you are doing to rotate or spin an object.